# Get the child type from the parent in typeorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm, typegraphql

I have a typeorm entity that uses single table inheritance:

```
@Entity()
@TableInheritance({ column: { type: "varchar", name: "type" } })
@ObjectType({ isAbstract: false })
export class OrganisationEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Field(() => [UserEntity])
  @OneToMany(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.organisation)
  users: UserEntity[];
}
```

and some child entities:

```
@ChildEntity()
@ObjectType()
class MedicalOrganisation {

}

@ChildEntity()
@ObjectType()
class SoftwareOrganisation {

}

@ChildEntity()
@ObjectType()
class MedicalOrganisation {

}
```

I'm wondering how I can get the type and the child properties from the parent organisation so that I can do something like:

```
const organisation = await OrganisationEntity.findOne()
if(organisation.type === "medicalOrganisation"){
...
}
```

But it seems I'm not allowed to access the type property through the parent. Does anyone know how this can be done?

I'd prefer not to use `instanceof` because it requires the child entities and is causing circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two options. Either use `.createQueryBuilder` and get the item using `getRawOne` and the returned object would contain a field named `OrganisationEntity_type` which can be used to do the checks. It's value would either be `'MedicalOrganisation'`, or `'SoftwareOrganisation'` and so on.

```
const orgRepository: Repository<OrganisationEntity> = getRepository(OrganisationEntity);
let organisation = await orgRepository.createQueryBuilder().getRawOne();

// organisation = {
//   OrganisationEntity_name: 'name',
//   OrganisationEntity_users: [
//     {},
//     {}
//   ],
//   OrganisationEntity_type: 'MedicalOrganisation'
// }
```

Or, you could add the field `type` in the `OrganisationEntity` itself like this:

```
@Entity()
@TableInheritance({ column: { type: "varchar", name: "type" } })
@ObjectType({ isAbstract: false })
export class OrganisationEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Field(() => [UserEntity])
  @OneToMany(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.organisation)
  users: UserEntity[];

  @Column
  type: string;
}
```

and do a straightforward:

```
let organisation = await OrganisationEntity.findOne();

// organisation = 
// MedicalOrganisation {
//   name: 'name',
//   users: [{}, {}],
//   type: 'MedicalOrganisation'
// }
```

and you get the `type` field in the object itself.

Comment: Thanks, the first one works, however the second one looks ideal however it seems I have to manually add the type to each child , is that correct?

Comment: No, you don't need to. Just add the `type` to parent entity. When you're querying using any child entity, you know the type anyway.

Comment: I had to add a hook to get this to work because the type wasn't being set on the children but now it works, thanks you!